# How to read a file creating a list

Tags: list, prolog

I have some code, looks like this:

```
main :-
    open('input.txt', read, Input),
    repeat,
    read_line_to_codes(Input, Line),
    maplist(my_representation, Line, FinalLine),
    ( Line \= end_of_file -> writeln(FinalLine), fail ; true ),
    close(Input).
```

`FinalLine` is a list of integers, including some underscores (based on the input file). Since this loops, I am wondering how to dynamically, each iteration of the loop, add the `FinalLine` list to another list. Basically this will create a list of lists.

And since I know the specifications of my input file, I know it loops 16 times, therefore I want a list of 16 lists. So although I don't know how to do this, I am pretty sure the best way would be to make a predicate that I call, instead of the output I am doing now (`writeln(FinalLine)`), to dynamically create this list of lists.

Hope this makes sense. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While historically I/O in Prolog was often presented in terms of `repeat`/`fail` loops, recursion is often (almost always?) the superior way to implement iteration. Especially if you need to remember data from one iteration to the next; failing causes backtracking, which unbinds your variables from the previously computed data. On backtracking you lose any data you had not saved away using yet more impure constructs. Recursion is simpler.

Recursion forces you to decompose the program into more than one predicate, but that is a good idea anyway. For example, separating opening the stream from reading it makes your program more reusable and more testable, because streams may be constructed from things other than files.

```
% dummy
my_representation(Codes, Result) :-
    atom_codes(Result, Codes).

stream_representations(Input, Lines) :-
    read_line_to_codes(Input, Line),
    (   Line == end_of_file
    ->  Lines = []
    ;   my_representation(Line, FinalLine),
        Lines = [FinalLine | FurtherLines],
        stream_representations(Input, FurtherLines) ).

main :-
    open('input.txt', read, Input),
    stream_representations(Input, Lines),
    close(Input),
    writeln(Lines).
```

Test input file:

```
hello
world
hello, world!
this file ends here
```

Test run:

```
?- main.
[hello,world,hello, world!,this file ends here]
true.
```

Comment: I'd go as far as to say that recursion allows Prolog to step through a problem, solving one part of it at a time, until it reaches a conclusion. Every separate rule is just a path to take to an end condition, after which it follows back the stack to its original caller with the answer. Which of course can be no, or yes for one or more solutions.

Answer (score -1):

A 2-dimensional list of lists is a matrix, and the easiest way to visualize it in your head is a table consisting of rows and columns. Here's a piece of example code to clarify the concept.

This code generates a matrix based on the maximum amounts of columns you want as `MaxX`, and the maximum amount of rows you want as `MaxY`. Each position in the matrix has a `cell(point(X,Y))` coordinate to visualize the output more easily.

```
%If the MaxY has been reached for the Y axis, step back
generate_matrix([],_,_,MaxY,MaxY) :- !.
%If MaxX has been reached, new row
generate_matrix([Row|Tp],X,MaxX,Y,MaxY):-
    generate_row(Row, X, MaxX, Y),
    Y1 is Y+1,
    generate_matrix(Tp,0,MaxX,Y1,MaxY).

%If the MaxX has been reached for the X axis, step back
generate_row([], MaxX,MaxX,_) :- !.
generate_row([cell(point(X,Y))|T], X, MaxX, Y) :-
    XNew is X + 1,
    generate_row(T, XNew, MaxX, Y).
```

You could easily replace `cell(point(X,Y)` with something you want to place there instead. I hope this clarifies the concept for you, be sure to ask for clarification if it doesn't.

Testquery to generate a 10 by 10 matrix/grid/table/2-dimensional list of lists:

```
%generate_matrix(Matrix, 0, MaxX, 0, MaxY)
generate_matrix(Matrix, 0, 10, 0, 10).
```

You can add dimensions to represent more complex structures. Adding a Z-axis gives you a 3D-cube.

Comment: This question is about reading from input and storing in lists, what you are answering is something completely different about Matrix, points etc.. maybe you messed it up with another question i guess??  (p.s: I didn't downvote you).

Comment: @coder - The title of the question is literally "Dynamically create a list of lists", does it really matter where the data comes from that fills the lists?

Comment: The question's title is badly chosen. The "list of lists" part comes from the fact that the OP wants to compute one list of results per line of the file; but what the question is really about is how to compute *some* result for each line of the file. Note that the accepted answer does not, in fact, create a list of lists but a list of atoms.

Comment: Yes because the OP describes a very specific situation where needs help with creating lists, your answer is like answering a different problem but yes using/creating lists, this doesn't helps at all. When I saw your answer initially I thought it was answering another answer, anyway that's my opinion (as I said didn't downvote but I don't think it is helpful)

Comment: @coder - I disagree, people are going to find this question thinking it's about dynamically creating lists to represent complex data structures. What kind of inputstream is used to fill the lists is irrelevant, as dynamically creating lists is about the lists, not creating the content.